# Is it possible to get a facebook user conversations using Facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

What I'm trying to do is Authorize my Facebook APP to manage user profile and get their list of conversations and list it in my site and also they can reply on the conversations through my site is this possible to do?

If not possible do you have any suggestions.

Thank you in advance happy coding

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/conversations/

Comment: You can not get any user-to-user messages. Only communication between a user and a page can be handled via API, and that only from the page’s end.